# Simple Web Scraping with Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, lxml

I haven't been able to find a simple way to do this, i have been following [this](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/)
and I have written the following,

```
##just comments before this
    import lxml,requests
 23 page = requests.get('https://finalexams.rutgers.edu.html')
 24 
 25 tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
 26 
 27 tableRow = tree.xpath('//tr/text() ' )
 28 
 29 print 'Rows' , tableRow
```

That script needs to parse through table rows like these and take out the things inside of them, but there could be a potentially infinite amount of table rows. I don't know how to access nested tags and they don't have unique names or ID's for me to look for.

How can I write a for loop that gets each of these table rows and lets me grab the individual bits of them?

```
  <tr>
    <td> 04264</td>
    <td>01:198:205</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>INTR DISCRET STRCT I</td>



  <td>C</td>
  <td>Dec 17, 2014:  8:00 AM - 11:00 AM </td>




  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td> 09907</td>
    <td>01:198:214</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>SYSTEMS PROGRAMMING</td>



  <td>C</td>
  <td>Dec 18, 2014:  8:00 PM - 11:00 PM </td>




  </tr>
```

Comment: `tree = html.fromstring(page.text)` isn't going to work with `import lxml`; did you do a `from lxml import html` somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to find the `tr` elements themselves, instead of their (empty) text, just search for the `tr` elements, instead of their text:

```
rows = tree.xpath('//tr')
```

And then you can iterate them:

```
for row in rows:
```

And then you can either search each one for `td` elements (e.g., by using `row.xpath`, or `row.findall`, etc.), or just assume all their children are `td` elements (as they happen to be in this case):

```
    for column in row:
```

And then you can do whatever it is you wanted to do with each column, like extract its text:

```
        print column.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all `tr` tags and make an inner loop over `td` tags for every row, example:

```
from lxml.html import fromstring

data = """
your html here
"""

root = fromstring(data)
for index, row in enumerate(root.xpath('//table/tr')):
    print "Row #%s" % index

    for cell in row.findall('td'):
        print cell.text.strip()

    print "----"
```

Prints:

```
Row #0
04264
01:198:205
01
INTR DISCRET STRCT I
C
Dec 17, 2014:  8:00 AM - 11:00 AM
----
Row #1
09907
01:198:214
01
SYSTEMS PROGRAMMING
C
Dec 18, 2014:  8:00 PM - 11:00 PM
----
```